# Not able to fetch border properties in mozilla and IE using jquery's .css()

Tags: jquery, css, border

In my table I am using below mentioned tr and giving border using style.

```
<tr id="test"  name="test1" style="border: 2px solid !important">
```

While using jquery

```
 $(this).css('border-bottom')
```

returns appropriate values in chrome but not in mozilla and IE. I tried many shorthand properties as well such as ***borderStyle***, ***borderBottomWidth***, ***borderBottomColor*** but no success.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I recreated the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/ppdtzxsa/1/ can't solve it neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all, your html table is not complete. ***It matters.***
2. When your css is read by browser, `border: 2px solid #000;` is interpreted to multiple, specific properties. You need to target a specific css property, for example: `border-bottom-width`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var border1 =  $('#test').css('border-bottom-width');
    alert(border1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="test" style="border: 2px solid #000 !important;">sdsds</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```